# fake p12 and mobileprovision for phonegap

Tags: ios, cordova

I use `phonegap` for making an iOS application. I want a fake certificate  file for building my ios app.
I find a fake `p12` file but when I build the app, it shows the following error:

> Error - Certificate doesn't match profile: The default keychain
>   doesn't have an identity matching

Answer (score 1):

I don't think fake things work for making any certificate for iphone or mac os, you have to register your system csr file to developer account and then you have to permit to get register in your key chain, thats way certificate works. Else you cant test your app in legal way, and i dont know about some hacking thing about it or else..